# Changing Chart.js chart type doesn't remove older axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I'm building a graph visualization based on chart.js library.
I'm allowing the user to change from a linear to a radar type of graph, based on the selection of a select combobox.
When going from a line chart to a radar, and back, both of the linear and radial axis are displaying. I tried to look for a "Clear axis" function but couldn't find one.

Is there any way to force redrawing the correct axis based on a chart type ?

You can find an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ThibaudMZN/nvgtju5r/8/).

Here's my basic HTML and JS/JQuery code :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<select id="chartType0">
  <option value="line">Line</option>
  <option value="radar">Radar</option>
</select>
<canvas id="chart0"></canvas>
```

JQuery :

```
$(function() {

    $("#chartType0").change(function() {
    var type = $("#chartType0 option:selected").val();
    var chartObj = $("#chart0").data("graph");
    chartObj.config.type = type;
    chartObj.update();
  });

  var ctx = $("#chart0");
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [5, 10, 5, 7, 20, 30, 45]
      }]
    }
  });
  ctx.data("graph", chart);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `update` method works only with new data. For new types you will need to create a new chart every time.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#chartType0").change(function() { createChart($(this).val()) })

  function createChart(type) {
    new Chart($("#chart0"), {
      type: type,
      data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Dataset',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          data: [5, 10, 5, 7, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
      }
    })
  }

  createChart('line')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<select id="chartType0">
  <option value="line">Line</option>
  <option value="radar">Radar</option>
</select>
<canvas id="chart0"></canvas>
```

Comment: That's a shame, because my actual chart has a lot more than that, event bindings to different tables and all this kind of stuff... Not sure how to handle a copy of all of those when creating a new one !

Comment: @TmZn I could suggest moving all that into the `createChart` function..

Comment: Problem is that those bindings happens depending on user interactions, pressing buttons, changing data source etc.. Anyway, thanks for the tips, I was expecting something more simple, like drawing a new set of axis...